# Xamarin.Forms.Navigation.PopAsync() Does Not Pop Page

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin.Forms, when we use `Navigation.PopAsync()`, the page does not pop in iOS.

After `PopAsync()` the same page remains.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Call the Proper Pop Method

If you pushed the page onto the Navigation Stack using `Navigation.PushAsync()`, use `Navigation.PopAsync()` to pop the page off of the Navigation Stack.

If you pushed the page on to the Navigation Stack using `Navigation.PushModalAsync()`, use `Navigation.PopModalAsync()` to pop the page off of the Navigation Stack.

## Use BeginInvokeOnMainThread

All UI updates must be done on the main thread. To ensure that this request is happening on the main thread, use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Navigation.PopAsync());
```

or

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Navigation.PopModalAsync());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Disappointed that this is needed. It suggests that the concrete implementation is using 2 stacks which allows for the possibility of the wrong page being displayed. Windows sometimes opens forms 'behind' the application. Has anyone ever seen the same problem Xamarin?